# php sql formatting SELECT columns numbers

Tags: php, sql, number-formatting

I am retrieving various columns from an SQL table and some of those are numeric or currency, in a sample let’s say:

```
$sql="SELECT id_column, event_column, amount_column FROM table1";
```

Then I show them using that:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>event time</th>
          <th>amount</th>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[' id_column '] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[' event_column '] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[' amount_column '] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Is it possible to change the format numbers get out in amount_column?

I saw should be possible to use a command to change a single number data the way I wuold like - number_format($number, 2, ',', '.') – but this seems not to apply for entire columns

What I do need is using comma for decimal under one (yy) and point for others grouped by 3 (x.xxx) thousands, something like xx.xxx.xxx,yy

Does some one have any suggestion? (including how to change the settings in PHP or SQL by the moment when I entry the data via form those have a comma instead of point for decimal but SQL save them in a different way – UK/USA decimal punctuation I guess while I need EU Italian/Germany punctuation or at least the ISO standard using comma for decimal and space for each group of three numbers).

Comment: what do you mean *but this seems not to apply for entire columns*? you did not apply this function anywhere in your code posted.

Comment: Just use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the numbers the way you want them to be.

Comment: why do you need a function that applies to an entire column?  you are already iterating over each row in the data set with your `while()` loop; simply wrap `$row[' amount_column ']` in a call to `number_format()` right where you are `echo`ing it as a `<td>`

Comment: @Alex I tried it but was clearly wrong since did not function, normally to avoid misunderstanding do not post in my example what I already know is not ok

Comment: @dave I tried but did not worked of, of course my syntax has to be wrong somewhere, can you post an example?

Comment: @landru27 that's what tried to do but had not positive feedback, as had wrote before I'm quite sure my syntax was bad. Also using the one proposed from Michael down here had some problems. Can you give me a complete example?

Comment: `echo "<td>" . number_format($row['amount_column'], 2, ',', ' ') . "</td>";`

Comment: @Alex had tried that, actually you removed spaces from the one was using, but am experiencing the same issue: the numbers are correctly formatted but values are all equal to 0 - which is not in the table. Is there something else I should do in the php statemente before?

Comment: If you have zeroes in your database - that is what you get. If you don't - show us proof! `die(var_dump($row));`

Comment: @Alex where should I use   die(var_dump($row));  to get the error code?

Comment: anywhere where `$row` exists. In our case it seem next line after `while` loop open. And you don't need to get error code. so far we never mentioned any error happened, only `0` values problem

Comment: @Alex am not able to change data as in the example in few time, hope you can understand: array(8) { [0]=> string(2) "30" ["id_elenco_spesa"]=> string(2) "30" [1]=> string(9) "trasporti" ["voce"]=> string(9) "trasporti" [2]=> NULL ["categoria"]=> NULL [3]=> string(4) "5.86" ["importo"]=> string(4) "5.86" }

Comment: yes, I can clearly see that there is no `amount_column` data at all here, same as `event_column` and same as `id_column` which means that you are completely lost in code. So please post the code fragment you work with!!! your post is about something different than what your data prooves

Comment: do `die(var_dump($sql))` right before you call `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` to check what is in query.

Comment: @Alex sorry for that, double checked it a few time but it seems am using the same example column name instead of my own in SQL table. It works perfecty, thanks for your patient and attention. Completely sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer is my comment:

```
echo "<td>" . number_format($row['amount_column'], 2, ',', ' ') . "</td>";
```

You can not do:

```
$row[' amount_column ']
```

Spacing for array index count!

here is a proof https://ideone.com/FtPEc6

So technically the answer you've approved - is wrong.

Comment: newby.... always unrelaiable.... well, moved the check. Thanks again to you and others for their contributes!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Yes, true `money_format` works not on windows. Thanks Dave. :)

Use `number_format( $row[' amount_column '], 2, ',', '.')`

It gives you something like *123.456.789,12*

[PHP number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

---

(Not on windows!)

You can use php´s `money_format('%i', $row[' amount_column '])`

[PHP money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>event time</th>
          <th>amount</th>
        </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[' id_column '] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row[' event_column '] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . money_format('%i', $row[' amount_column ']) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```